# SVN post-commit script not being executed

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I have spent a couple weeks now trying to resolve this issue (without any progress).

I followed the svn redbook section "Implementing Repository Hooks" by:

- copying the $REPOSITORY_HOME/hooks/post-commit.tmpl file to $REPOSITORY_HOME/hooks/post-commit
- making the $REPOSITORY_HOME/hooks/post-commit script executable by the account that runs either httpd or svnserve (in fact, I made it executable by everyone)
- verifying that my post-commit script can be run manually by that same user on the command line

However, the post-commit script still fails to be executed whenever any user commits any artifacts to the repository.

One thing that I found within the svn redbook and the post-commit.tmpl that I am a bit confused of what exactly it is inferring is: 
"Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must have filesystem-level permission to access the repository."

Does this mean that the user which executes the post-commit script must also be a user that can access the SVN repository (through an SVN client such as tortoiseSVN or rather a local user account that can access SVN's repository files through something such as putty).  I believe this may be where my problem resides, but am not exactly convinced because the user who runs the httpd is the owner of the post-commit script and the filesystem the repository resides on.  Therefore, he has all the permissions he needs to the filesystem.  However, I am not able to checkout directories/files from the repository remotely using tortoiseSVN on my workstation using that user account.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Already reviewed references:

- [Post commit hook problem for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876365/post-commit-hook-problem-for)
- [SVN post-commit hook won't run after a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032531/svn-post-commit-hook-wont-run-after-a-commit)
- [how to install svn post-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577234/how-to-install-svn-post-commit-hook)
- [Trouble with SVN post-commit and Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521302/trouble-with-svn-post-commit-and-jenkins)
- [Subversion Post-Commit Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040244/subversion-post-commit-hooks)
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf
- http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-04/0391.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have got an error. I assume Post commit fails with a Warning message stating

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output: 
You need version 1.5.0 or better of the Subversion Python Bindings
```

If that is the case, I think you would have not set the environmental variable within the hook script. For security reasons, the Subversion repository executes hook programs with an empty environment — i.e., no environment variables are set at all, not even $PATH (or %PATH%, under Windows). Because of this, many administrators are baffled when their hook program runs fine by hand, but doesn't work when run by Subversion.

Note : Be sure to explicitly set any necessary environment variables in your hook program and/or use absolute paths to programs.

Answer (score 0):

If SVN server is hosted on linux, then you need to mark file as executable for that user:

```
chmod a+x $REPOSITORY_HOME/hooks/post-commit
```

If SVN server is hosted on windows, then you probably need to rename post-commit file to post-commit.bat